# Java : getting a referenced data base object and then modifying it

Tags: java, sql, database

here is my question, given this code:

```
studentOutcomeService.getAll()
                     .get(getStudentOutcomeByID(
                            selectedStudentOutcome.getId().intValue()))
                     .setDescription(description);

studentOutcomeService.getAll()
                     .get(getStudentOutcomeByID(
                            selectedStudentOutcome.getId().intValue()))
                     .setSequenceNumber(Integer.valueOf(sequenceNumber));

studentOutcomeService.getAll()
                     .get(getStudentOutcomeByID(
                            selectedStudentOutcome.getId().intValue()))
                     .setShortName(shortName);

studentOutcomeService.getAll()
                     .get(getStudentOutcomeByID(
                            selectedStudentOutcome.getId().intValue()))
                     .setIdentifier(identifier);
```

I am unhappy with the fact that I am querying the database 4 times to constantly update a field.

I trued creating a StudentOutcome object and storing what was found in there, and then modifying that Object I created, but it seems like when a new object is created despite being set equal to the one found in the database, using the =, operator, the changes made to the new StudentOutcome object does NOT apply to what it was initially set equal to.

How can I make this more efficient? I know there is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
StudentOutcome toUpdate = studentOutcomeService.getAll().get(
    getStudentOutcomeByID(selectedStudentOutcome.getId()));
toUpdate.setDescription(description);
toUpdate.setSequenceNumber(Integer.valueOf(sequenceNumber));
toUpdate.setShortName(shortName);
toUpdate.setIdentifier(identifier);
```

or even just

```
StudentOutcome toUpdate = getStudentOutcomeByID(selectedStudentOutcome.getId());
toUpdate.setDescription(description);
toUpdate.setSequenceNumber(Integer.valueOf(sequenceNumber));
toUpdate.setShortName(shortName);
toUpdate.setIdentifier(identifier);
```

Comment: so now when toUpdate is modified, since it was initially set to what was found in the DB, its updates will apply to the object in the database as well?

Comment: If you want to update the database, you have to update the database separately.  Messing with Java objects doesn't generally update databases automatically.

Comment: my question is updating that database entry, which is whole purpose of that. Would I have to that many queries to modify each column?

Comment: You need just one query to update the whole object.  But this wasn't in your original code example, so I didn't put it here either.